# Sending var model to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an entity query below.I want to send it to my view.

```
using (Entities entity = new Entities())
        {

            var data = entity.Pages
              .Join(entity.Images, 
                    pgs => pgs.Id, 
                    img => img.PageId, 
                    (pgs, img) => new { Page = pgs, Image = img })
              .Where(pgsimg=>pgsimg.Image.Status);


            return View("Detail", data);
        }
```

and inside view I wrote
`@model IQueryable<Page>`
but it does not work. How can I send this data to view as model?

Comment: By sending this to a view, you are causing business logic code to execute in a view, that's breaks the design of MVC.  Your code should actually enumerate the data in the controller.

Comment: @Blast What do you mean "it does not work", are you getting an exception? Nothing displays?

Comment: You might want to create a model with a field where you can store the 'data' value and pass that field to the view instead of the 'data' .